# Angular-datatable responsive

Tags: html, css, angularjs, datatable, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating a responsive SPA.In this app,I am having problem while trying to use angular-datatable within a div tag.
    Here is the jsfiddle link /8sveskkh/
Please guide me how to make sure that my datatable resides within contained div.

Comment: Does the jsfiddle include Bootstrap?

Comment: What exactly the problem here? Do you want the table to occupy fully its parent div?

Comment: The datatable should be within the border of outer div which does not happen when we reduce screen size

Comment: But your fiddle does not include Bootstrap css

Comment: Check this fiddle if it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/n0ze6e8s/

Comment: Even in this fiddle if the entire content is placed in a div,then on reducing the size of the screen the datatable will come out of div since due to word wrap will header of column expands

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the `table` in a `div` with `.table-responsive` class to make it not to overflow its container.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n0ze6e8s/3/).

Comment: What a clever answer. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party plugin to have data-table as responsive.

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

Configure dtOptions as follows:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
        // Active Responsive plugin
        .withOption('responsive', true);
```

please refer : http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withResponsive for other customize options, this will make yo day.